# How to access data generated in one @Test method to another test method but in different class

Tags: java, testng, rest-assured

```
@Test(description = "Generate access token")
    public void AuthenticationApiTC_30() throws IOException, SQLException {

    Map<String, String> positiveDataMap = operations.readRecordFromXls(XLSPATH, FILENAME, POSITIVESHEET);
    AuthenticateBuilder builder = new AuthenticateBuilder();
    Response response = REQUEST
            .headers(builder.authHeaderBuilderForGetReq(positiveDataMap.get("mobilenumber"),
                    positiveDataMap.get("ssoToken"), positiveDataMap.get("osVersion"),
                    positiveDataMap.get("deviceID"), positiveDataMap.get("imsi"),
                    positiveDataMap.get("deviceIDType"), positiveDataMap.get("applicationID"),
                    positiveDataMap.get("version"), positiveDataMap.get("os")))
            .basePath(BASEPATH)
            .get();

    log.info("AuthenticationApiTC_30\n" + response.prettyPrint());
    PostValidators.checkMessageInResponse(response, SuccessMessage.Success);
    accessToken =  Utils.extractDataFromResponse(response, "result.accessToken");
    log.info("Token string :: " + accessToken);
}
```

My requirement is to get `accessToken` generated in above `@Test` method and pass it to another `@Test` method present in different class.

P.S : I have to do this process again and again as `accessToken` will be different for different users and test cases.

Comment: You don't. one of the reasons for this is: you can't guarantee the order in which they run. They should be run completely independent from one another. Why not put the code you need to run in an @Before, or a method you call from both tests?

Comment: @Stultuske Actually, regarding first point I don't want to execute that method each time by adding it to '@Before' and second I tried it but I am interested in response generated by that method and trying to use it as an input to second method in different class.

Comment: So ... your Test is supposed to test another test?

Comment: Yes, you are right...

Comment: and how are you going to test the test that is supposed to test the test? if you need a construction like this, all it means is your tests are worthless, because you don't trust them.

Comment: I don't need to test it again, I just need the data from that test case which I will get only when I execute that test method and that data I will use to drive the next test case but only issue is here I am using TestNG test method not a normal java method and other method is present in different class, I already have a way around but that is not as per the standards as I am returning some data in @Test method, that is the reason I am seeking some help over here.

Comment: Consider each test as a separate individual unit and running on its own. Writing test cases this way is actually good practice to identify the particular problem and provide a fix for that code path. If you think some of your implementation is repetitive and need not repeat the same in each test method, then have static method and execute the same from each of your test methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use normal methods inside your test classes. Instead of having a `@Before` method, which gets called on every test method, you can create a static helper method which gets called only for some of your test methods. So you can do something like this:

```
public static Foobar requestToken() {
    // ...
}

@Test
public void someTestMethod() {
    Foobar x = TestClass.requestToken();

    // work with 'x'
}

@Test
public void someOtherTestMethod() {
    Foobar x = TestClass.requestToken();

    // do other test with 'x'
}
```

So you don't need to rewrite any code which requests a token but instead use this helper method.